# Sequelize hook afterUpdate How to get dirty fields, original value and updated value?

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I'm stuck with sequelize hooks, trying to write every change to a model into a log table. Therefore I'm looking for a way to access the models data before and after the write to MySQL.

How can I access this data within Sequelize Hook afterUpdate?

How can I get the updated/changed/dirty fields?

How can I access data before and after the update to make diffs?

Answer (score 8):

Hook functions first argument is instance. As long as instance is fetched ahead of update operation, `instance._previousDataValues` and `instance._change` are available.

```
sequelize.addHook(
  "afterCreate",
  (i) => {
    console.log(i);
  }
);
```

Comment: `instance._changed` is available, not `_change`

Answer (score 1):

Use `instance.dataValues` and `instance._previousDataValues` to access values after and before object update. This is valid for instance hooks, not bulk hooks. taken from [Sequelize Hooks- Previous data values for afterBulkUpdate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53255911/sequelize-hooks-previous-data-values-for-afterbulkupdate)

Answer (score 0):

```
    module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
        const ContractLineItem = sequelize.define('ContractLineItem', {
            id: {
                type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
                field: 'id',
                allowNull: false,
                primaryKey: true,
                autoIncrement: true
            }
            //more attributes here
        }, {
            schema: 'public',
            tableName: 'ContractLineItem',
            timestamps: true
        });


        ContractLineItem.beforeBulkUpdate((contractLineItem, options) => {    
            console.log("b4 update contractLineItem....contractLineItem._change =" + contractLineItem._change);

            if (!contractLineItem._change){
                console.log("nothing changed.............");
                //skip updating record
                //return next();
            }else{
                console.log("something changed................");
                //update record
            }
            console.log("after checking on change....");
        });

        ContractLineItem.associate = (models) => {

            ContractLineItem.belongsTo(models.Contract, {
                foreignKey: 'contractId',
            });
            //more relationships

        };
        return ContractLineItem;
    };
```

Comment: the output of the console log is : b4 update contractLineItem....contractLineItem._change =undefined, any idea why it's undefined?

Comment: because you should use `._changed` and not `._change`