# Sequelize Hooks- Previous data values for afterBulkUpdate

Tags: sequelize.js

I am trying to create a hook `beforeBulkUpdate` and get new and previous values of a field. I tried using `.reload()` on the model and `_previousDataValues` but they only work on instances and not bulk create and update (I'm using bulk update). Is there a way to get the previous value of field using the `beforeBulkUpdate` hook?

```
beforeBulkUpdate: (person) => {
  console.log(person.name) // 'John' (new name)
  Person.findOne({ where: { id: input.id } }).then(person => {
  person.reload().then(() => {
    console.log(person.name) // 'John' (expected old name, but returns new name)
    })
  })
}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Solved it by passing `individualHooks:true` to the call.

```
Model.update({id: input.id}, { individualHooks: true});
```

And:

```
hooks: {
      beforeUpdate: (instance, options) => {
        console.log(instance.dataValues); // new values
        console.log(instance._previousDataValues); // current values
      }
    }
```